# Multiple inputs into the base of a single FET

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, input

I've been wondering if the below configuration would work: essentially using a single FET (instead of a 3 input OR gate) to determine if a clock signal can be read by a sequence of binary counters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fia18z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Am I taking anything for granted here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Without a clear definition of "work" the answer is probably no. What is the Vgs(th) of the FET, what are the input and output voltages, how are you loading the source, and what voltage swing do you need on the counters? If you have trouble answering these, go for the OR gate.

Comment: Advice: don't join the Q outputs together and don't ground the Qbar outputs - these are outputs not some piece of string you can tie to a peg or each other. Also, if you want your counters to increment, don't tie the "increment input" to ground.

Comment: grounding your ¬Q outputs is *definitely* going to break things, don't do that.

Comment: @BrianDrummond given my lack of experience it definitely sounds like I should stick with what I know and go for the OR gate then! Thanks for all the interesting terms for me to learn, though, hopefully that'll equip me better for next time!

Comment: @Hearth Is it simply a matter of using a pull down resistor?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. A resistor to ground wouldn't break things but it would probably waste power. Why do you think they need to be connected to anything at all?

Comment: @Hearth ahhh I see, so I can just leave them floating! Thank you

Comment: @jonny They won't be floating. They're outputs, and the SR latches you've drawn here don't have any sort of OE input.